# If I accept a parameter via universal reference, is exactly one of is_rvalue_reference and is_lvalue_reference true?

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

Is it ever possible for this code to print "neither"?

```
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t) {
    if constexpr (is_lvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        cout << "lv" << endl;
    } else if constexpr (is_rvalue_reference_v<T>) {
        cout << "rv" << endl;
    } else {
        cout <<"neither" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, exactly one of `is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>` and `is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>` would be true. @songyuanyao Oops, sorry.

Comment: @L.F. Fine. I got what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it ever possible for this code to print "neither"?

Yes, "neither" will be printed any time an rvalue is passed to `foo` and no explicit template parameter is given:

```
foo(42);  // "neither" is printed because T is deduced as int
```

Or when a non-reference type is explicitly specified:

```
int i=0;
// "neither" is printed because T is explicitly specified as int:
foo<int>(std::move(i));
```

---

While `T` can be a non-reference type, the type of `t` will always be a reference type.  There are three possibilities for the type of `t`:

1. `T` is a value type (i.e. `int`): the type of `t` is `int&&`; rvalue-reference to `int`.
2. `T` is an lvalue-reference (i.e. `int&`): the type of `t` is `int& &&`, which collapses to `int&`; lvalue-reference to `int`.
3. `T` is an rvalue-reference (i.e. `int&&`): the type of `t` is `int&& &&`, which collapses to `int&&`; rvalue-reference to `int`.

This is the mechanism by which forwarding references work.  If you pass an rvalue to `foo`, then `T` will be deduced to be a value type.  If you pass an lvalue then `T` will be deduced to be an lvalue-reference type.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you want to note that `foo<int>(i)` will fail to compile (so it won't print anything). Passing `std::move(i)` solves it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Heh, it had `std::move` originally, but I though "lets make it so the explicit parameter is different than what would be deduced" and broke it.  Added it back.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ever possible for this code to print "neither"?

Yes.

```
foo(5); // neither
```

> If I accept a parameter via universal reference, is exactly one of is_rvalue_reference and is_lvalue_reference true?

The parameter `t` will either have rvalue reference type or lvalue reference type. The type `T` on the other hand will be different depending on deduction and [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) rules. If instead you change `is_lvalue/rvalue_reference<T>` to `is_lvalue/rvalue_reference<decltype(t)>` then the else path can never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ever possible for this code to print "neither"?

Yes. According to the rule of type deduction for [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), when being passed an lvalue, `T` will be deduced an lvalue-reference type, when being passed an rvalue, `T` will be deduced as a non-reference type. e.g.

```
int i;
foo(i); // T is deduced as int&
foo(0); // T is deduced as int
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gwn8oJcsn29ujRpN)

On the other hand, `"rv"` won't be printed unless specifying the template argument explicitly.

On the other hand (again), if you check the type of the function parameter `t`, it'll be either an lvalue-reference type or an rvalue-reference type; `"neither"` will neither be printed.

```
int i;
foo(i);        // T is deduced as int&, the type of t is int& (int& && -> int&)
foo(0);        // T is deduced as int, the type of t is int&&
foo<int&&>(0); // T is specified as int&&, the type of t is int&& (int&& && -> int&&)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7esAkttHds1sFkZt)